# Get parsed entries for Distribution/module metada from PKG-INFO (Python pkg_resources)

Tags: python, python-packaging, pkg-resources

I'm currently using code similar to this

```
# Returns PKG-INFO in "email format", meaning it looks a little like this:
#   Name: some_python_module
#   Version: 1.2.3
dist = pkg_resources.get_distribution('some_python_module')
pkginfo = dist.get_metadata(dist.PKG_INFO)

d = dict(line.split(': ', 1) for line in pkginfo.split('\n') if ': ' in line)
print(d['Name'])
```

**I'm wondering if there is a "clean" way to do this key lookup for a Distribution object?**

Note I am using custom properties here so doing `dist.project_name` or `dist.version` are not enough in my particular case.

Comment: I am confused about the difference between PKG-INFO and METADATA. Both seem to contain the same information? But sometimes PKG-INFO seems to be missing?

Comment: `python setup.py install` seems to result in `PKG-INFO` and `python setup.py bdist_wheel` in `METADATA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stolen from `_parsed_pkg_info` in `DistInfoDistribution`:

```
dist = pkg_resources.get_distribution('some_python_module')
pkginfo = dist.get_metadata(dist.PKG_INFO)

parsed = email.parser.Parser().parsestr(pkginfo)
print(parsed['Name'])
```

Not sure why this method is not in `Distribution` as it appears to work for both `DistInfoDistribution` and `EggInfoDistribution` -- this is what `dist.PKG_INFO` is for by the way, this variable differs between those two (`'METADATA'` for `.dist-info` and `'PKG-INFO'` for `.egg-info`).

Little note: `parsestr` returns a `FeedParser` object which outputs the *parsed input feed* when you call `print` on it -- do not get confused by this, it's not a `str`. Also note that spaces are not allowed in key names by [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.2) and lead to silent parser errors!